# php .net data exchange

Tags: php, .net

We have 2 web applications, one running in php/apache and  the other one is in .net/IIS. How can we possibly exchange data between these two web applications?

Basically the process is we exchange data from/to our php web application and the .net web application using the REST API. How can we do that in php...? I never had any experience handling .net web applications and communicating with them.

Any suggestions and ideas are really appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Data exchange and integration are two completely different topics, you can exchange data with web services like REST or SOAP.

Comment: thanks, I see... I think I mean data exchange and not integration. I'll modify my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the exchange to happen on the web pages? Or are either one or both web services? Either way, the best way to transfer data like that is using JSON (http://www.w3schools.com/json/) - it does not have the structure or overhead of XML and .NET, PHP and JavaScript can iterate through the data.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I'll look more into it. Yes basically we need the exchange to happen on both web pages.

Comment: Glad I could help - then you will need to use JavaScript to call functions on the other server and format the data. Without more detail, thats what I would suggest.